# Clear filter from RadGrid

Tags: c#, jquery, radgrid

I wanna clear filter from RadGrid using jquery.
I am adding new row in the grid but if filter is already set, It doesn't show newly added row so I wanna clear filter.
I there any way to clear RadGrid filter using jquery?

Comment: Were you able to use my answer, or do you really need JQuery for this?  If you really need it, I can try to update my answer for completeness.

Answer (score 0):

Just use Telerik's JavaScript API like this:

```
var grid = $find("<%= RadGrid1%>"),
    masterTableView = grid.get_masterTableView();
masterTableView.get_filterExpressions().clear();
masterTableView.rebind()
```

You don't even need JQuery for this.  Form elements in the RadGrid are deeply nested and very cumbersome to access directly, hence the easy-to-use JavaScript API provided by Telerik.

Check out [this forum post](http://www.telerik.com/forums/radgrid-clear-filter-at-client---side) for more discussion.

Comment: Any reason for the downvote other than the fact that I recommended against using JQuery?  If you use JQuery, it's going to be something awfully ugly like `$find('RadGrid1_ctrl00_grid').grid.data.control[4].data.cell.innerHtml`.  There's a reason you should use the API over JQuery.

Comment: This does not work. After `.rebind()` all filter expressions are back. The same goes for the forum solution: filter fields are temporarily cleared until `.rebind()` restore them.